# Squid number of L1 and L2 directories

Tags: squid

I incresed the cache for my squid proxy. But i really do not understand the params before the size-MB param.

The reference show the fallow:

cache_dir scheme directory size-MB L1 L2

What is L1 and L2 params and how calculate the proper value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Configuring the number of sub directories**

There are two arguments to `cache_dir` named as L1 and L2. Squid stores the cacheable objects in a hierarchical fashion in directories named so that it'll be faster to lookup an object in the cache. The hierarchy is of two-levels, where L1 determines the number of directories at the first level and L2 determines the number of directories in each of the directories at
the first level. We should set L1 and L2 high enough so that directories at the second level don't have a huge number of files.

Let's see an example of the cache directory /squid_cache/ with 50GB of
free space:

```
cache_dir aufs /squid_cache/ 51200 32 512
```

We have a cache directory /squid_cache/ with 50 GB of free space with the values of L1 and L2 as 32 and 512 respectively. So, if we assume the average size of a cached object to be 16 KB, there will be 51200x1024÷(32x512x16) = 200 cached objects in each of the directories at the second level, which is quite good.

Read the Book Squid3 Beginners Guide

Comment: Thanks, is just what i needed.